# Is there a way to give a sequence to initializer of Union in Python typing

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have code that looks like this:

```
MY_SPECIAL_CLASSES = (Foo, Bar, Spam, Eggs)
```

I have many functions that take any of those as the input parameter,

so their signature is e.g.:

```
def whatever(obj: Union[Foo, Bar, Spam, Eggs]) -> None:
```

To me, the obvious solution - just use the common superclass - is explicitly stated as a no-no in PEP484 (emphasis mine)

> By default type variables are considered invariant , which means that
>   arguments for arguments annotated with types like `List[Employee]` must
>   exactly match the type annotation -- **no subclasses or superclasses of
>   the type parameter** (in this example `Employee` ) are allowed.

Since

```
def something(obj: Union[*MY_SPECIAL_CLASSES]) -> None:
```

does not work, I have to do something like:

```
UNION_OF_MY_SPECIAL_CLASSES = Union[Foo, Bar, Spam, Eggs]
def another(obj: UNION_OF_MY_SPECIAL_CLASSES) -> UNION_OF_MY_SPECIAL_CLASSES:
```

To me, that is ugly - and a clear violation of DRY.

To avoid DRY, I cand use the dunder-attribute `__union_set_params__` in my definition, but to me this way looks a bit unhygienic and backwards, e.g.

```
UNION_OF_MY_SPECIAL_CLASSES = Union[Foo, Bar, Spam, Eggs]
MY_SPECIAL_CLASSES = tuple(UNION_OF_MY_SPECIAL_CLASSES.__union_set_params__)
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: It seems to me like you're misreading the PEP. The default invariance of type variables means that it's an error to pass a `Foo[Subclass]` where a `Foo[Superclass]` is expected, but it's fine to pass a `Subclass` to a parameter annotated as `SuperClass`.

Comment: D'uh. I feel like an idiot... make that an answer and I'll accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misreading the PEP. The default invariance of type variables means that it's an error to pass a `Foo[Subclass]` where a `Foo[Superclass]` is expected, but it's fine to pass a `Subclass` to a parameter annotated as `SuperClass`.

As long as your function accepts any instance of the common superclass (so there isn't some 5th subclass you want to reject or anything), you should be fine to annotate those parameters with the superclass.